# Scrape youtube href using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using jsoup in java and I'm trying to scrape the first href in a particular youtube video search. However, I can't figure out the correct css query in order to obtain the href. If someone can point me in the correct direction, that'd be great. [Here is the image of the html I'm trying to scrape on youtube.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZNYq.png)

The following is one of the selects I've tried, but doesn't print out anything.

My code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WebTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=childish+gambino+this+is+america").get();
            Elements musicVideoLink = doc.select("h3.title-and-badge.style-scope.ytd-video-renderer a[href]");

            String linkh = musicVideoLink.attr("href");
            System.out.println(linkh);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){ }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just use `#video-title`

Comment: doc.select("#video-title") doesn't seem to work. Seems to not print anything still.

Comment: You're almost certainly swallowing an exception. Put `ex.printStackTrace();` in the catch block.

Comment: I've added that in and there's no exception from it.

Comment: Print `doc` and see what exactly was send back to you from server. Often when selector doesn't seem to work is because searched element is being placed dynamically by JavaScript later. In that case jsoup will not be able to help you because it is not browser emulator (it doesn't support JS) but *parser* so you would need to use other tool, possibly Selenium or other web-drivers.

Answer (score 0):

With the `JSoup.connect().get()`, because there are no other headers in the request like `User-Agent`, YouTube returns quite a basic HTML rendering of the search results.  This is quite different from the structure in the linked image above, but actually easier to select in though:

```
Elements musicVideoLink = doc.select("h3.yt-lockup-title a");
```

This looks like the easiest solution here.  If you do pass in the `User-Agent` header, you get back the same as the Network tab in the browser inspector shows, but this doesn't yet match the result in that image.  The browser clearly does a bit of AJAX style processing and rendering on that response next.